# Who vs Whom. Which one is appropriate?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, interrogatives, who-whom

- Who will you voting for in the Lok Sabha Elections 2014?
- Whom will you voting for in the Lok Sabha Elections 2014?

Which one is correct, and why? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Neither is correct - you must say either *...will you vote for...* or *...will you be voting for...*. Aside from that, *who* is acceptable in all but the most exquisitely formal contexts. If you're going to use *whom* you should also 'pied-pipe' the preposition: *For whom will you be voting...?*

Comment: First one is correct? If I say: What are you waiting for? Is it correct? Why who is acceptable in the above statements?

Comment: No. *Who will you **be** voting for ...* is ordinary English usage; the question is unlikely to arise in a context which would call for anything so pompous as *For whom will you be voting ...*

Comment: I didn't get your sentence after semi colon. Can you use simpler English. Please? Can I say this: For whom will you be voting in the Lok Sabha Elections 2014?

Comment: You may say that, but it is **very formal**. In conversation you would say *Who will you be voting for...?*

Comment: But we use whom for the object. You is subject here, so I can't use Who technically. Right?

Comment: "Technically", yes; but it's a 19th-century technicality, and *whom* is on the verge of disappearing from Present-Day English.

Comment: What are you waiting for? OR For what are you waiting? Both are correct?

Comment: Yes, both. The first is colloquial, the second is very formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, "whom" is correct. The word is the object of the preposition "for", and so should use the object form of the word.

In practice, 99% of English speakers say "who", probably because the sentence is structured to put the preposition far from its object, and so it is not obvious what role each word is playing.

In general, use "who" when the word is the subject and "whom" when it is an object.

As StoneyB notes, you should say "vote for" or "be voting for", not just "voting for".

Comment: So, what is correct? Please be specific. :(

Comment: @hellodear - This answer is very specific. It depends on what your definition of "correct" is. Do you want to talk like everyone else? Or do you want to follow strict grammar technicalities?